# how to bundle images from paths in json file using parcel with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, parcel

I have a json file witch contains image paths. The images are in an image folder like this ..[image: json file with image path]

and when I generate an html template with vanilla javascript using parcel bundler it shows me nothing on screen.
I want bundle images from json file paths in dist folder to display them on screen.

[image: parcel]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i try to put image path from json file and it show's me nothing while using parcel ,, if i'm not using parcel all thing goes fine.